# Android NDK compilation error with struct stat

Tags: android, c++, struct, android-ndk

I have a problem to compile a code to android native. I get this error during compilation:

```
'struct stat' has no member named 'st_ctim'
```

In the header files of struct stat the struct is called 'st_ctime' (notice the 'e' in the end)

Is there a way i can compile the code without modifying it ?
Is there a version of android native API that comes with a struct stat (stat.h) containing member 'st_ctim' instead of 'st_ctime' ?

I'm compiling against Android native API level 26. So far i've seen that in API level 8, 9, 23 there is the same problem.

I'm reporting the problem with st_ctim, but every other member ends with an 'e' (st_atime, st_mtime)

For clarity purpose, why is there that difference between libc struct stat and android native struct stat ?

Comment: And which language is it? Don't spam tags for different languages!

Comment: @Olaf this is language C++, did I spam anything ? I'm using arm-linux-androideabi-g++ as compiler. The source code i'm trying to compile is written in C++

Comment: Yes, C is not C++; they are different languages!

Comment: @Olaf well thanks for the edit then. any clue about the problem itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

st_ctim is a newer member of stat, it contains nanosec precision time (struct timespec). Unfortunately, android doesn't have that. Here's an excerpt of the manual of lstat (of a linux machine):

```
struct stat {
      /* I stripped several members here (st_mode, etc.) */

      /* Since Linux 2.6, the kernel supports nanosecond
         precision for the following timestamp fields.
         For the details before Linux 2.6, see NOTES. */

         struct timespec st_atim;  /* time of last access */
         struct timespec st_mtim;  /* time of last modification */
         struct timespec st_ctim;  /* time of last status change */

#define st_atime st_atim.tv_sec      /* Backward compatibility */
#define st_mtime st_mtim.tv_sec
#define st_ctime st_ctim.tv_sec
};
```

> Older  kernels  and  older  standards  did  not  support nanosecond
>   timestamp fields.  Instead, there were three timestamp
>   fields—st_atime,
>          st_mtime, and st_ctime—typed as time_t that recorded timestamps with one-second precision.
>
> Since kernel 2.5.48, the stat structure supports nanosecond resolution for the three file timestamp fields.  The nanosecond 
>   components  of
>          each  timestamp  are  available  via names of the form st_atim.tv_nsec, if suitable feature test macros are defined. 
>   Nanosecond timestamps
>          were standardized in POSIX.1-2008, and, starting with version 2.12, glibc exposes the nanosecond  component  names  if  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  is
>          defined  with the value 200809L or greater, or _XOPEN_SOURCE is defined with the value 700 or greater.  Up to and including glibc
>   2.19, the
>          definitions of the nanoseconds components are also defined if _BSD_SOURCE or _SVID_SOURCE is defined.  If none of the aforementioned macros
>          are defined, then the nanosecond values are exposed with names of the form st_atimensec.

So your code relies on this new feature, I think you have to modify it use st_ctime instead of st_ctim.

Comment: thanks for the tip !! ok i changed the code accordingly and now it pass this step. I did not want to do that because it is not my code, but i guess i have no other option. thx

Comment: "Unfortunately, android doesn't have that." This isn't true if you're on a modern NDK.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a modern version of the NDK, you'll have a modern `struct stat`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/include/sys/stat.h

Note that you need to be using the NDK's [unified headers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r15-release/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md) to get the up to date headers. This is the default in r15, but opt-in for r14.

Comment: Funny thing is i'm using a prebuilt toolchain for cross compiling, which does not refer any option for using unified headers...and i'm also using latest ndk r15.. thanks for pointing me that. I'll update it accordingly to 1-use the unified headers and 2-use clang instead of gcc/g++ build system !!

Comment: "prebuilt toolchain" as in using the compilers straight from toolchains/blah and setting up all the compiler flags yourself? You should try using a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) if that's what you mean.